# PostgreSQL: How escape '?

Tags: postgresql, escaping, postgresql-9.3

My original sql:

`INSERT INTO clients (name, phone) VALUES ('Vs'emandon', '333026660');`

I read about E'' and tried this:

`INSERT INTO clients (name) VALUES ('VsE'''emandon);`

But this not working.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f717e/2

Comment: @MarcB: that's a non-standard way of escaping single quotes that has been deprecated years ago (and all current versions of Postgres have disabled this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres follows the SQL standard.

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

> To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes, e.g., `'Dianne''s horse'`. Note that this is **not** the same as a double-quote character (`"`).

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, phone) VALUES ('Vs''emandon', '333026660');
```